# Firestore onSnapshot: One query complex or multiple query simple

Tags: javascript, firebase, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

There are any cost or performance difference about creates **an onSnapshot with a complex clause** or creates **3 on Snapshots with a simple one**. In addition, the **posts** collection  has a rule which check in the **posts_permission** collection  if logged user has permission to read the posts. It's a mobile project, so I'm concerned with the performance and cost because the posts can be updated constantly.

**Complex clause:**

```
const query = db.collection('posts')
            .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ['id1','id2', 'id3']);
query.onSnapshot(snap => {console.log(snap)});
```

**Simple clauses:**

```
const query1 = db.collection("posts").doc("id1")
const query2 = db.collection("posts").doc("id2")
const query3 = db.collection("posts").doc("id3")
query1.onSnapshot(snap => {console.log(snap)});
query2.onSnapshot(snap => {console.log(snap)});
query3.onSnapshot(snap => {console.log(snap)});
```

Comment: You also need to consider that they are three different requests, one or two of them might experiment a network lag. Generally since the documents are indexed, they are better queried all at once

Answer (score 1):

In terms of cost, X documents read always just cost X document reads.  It doesn't matter how many queries it took.  You will also pay for each document read by the evaluation of a security rule.  It's really easy to compute the costs if you just follow the information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).  There are no hidden costs.

In terms of performance, there is really no big difference, between multiple queries and a single query. Unless you are dealing with very large amounts of documents, you will likely see comparable performance based on the size and number of documents, and the quality of the network connection.  All read documents are pipelined over a single connection, so there is no substantial difference in receiving documents from multiple listeners as opposed to one listener. You should benchmark this yourself if you have concerns.